# How can I ask a specific moderator a question?

Tags: support

I want to ask a specific moderator a question but I don't see any way to communicate directly with that person.   How can I?  My question is very specific to some internal nofollow rules this moderator mentioned, and am wondering if my website is blacklisted.   Thus I don't really think it's a general question for posting on Meta (but maybe I'm wrong).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd recommend you use chat for this. Either @ mention them in that SE site's main chat room, where they are hopefully regularly active. Alternatively, you can navigate to their chat profile and use the 'start a new room with this user' button to create a new chat room for the two of you.

Comment: This. And some sites have special rooms for talking with mods about stuff.